# Delete item from mongoDB

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, redux

So I have a react/redux app that is basically your standard movie search app. Im encountering a bit of a hiccup when it comes to deleting items out of the wishlist component though. When a user first saves a movie, its sent to the wishlist with the information from the generic response, however on the backend side, its as per usual, assigning each movie an objectID. The issue is that my movies in the wishlist don't have that objectID when you first load the wishlist. It's not until you refresh the browser that the movies have the objectID. I want users to be able to delete a movie from their wishlist as soon as they see it show up in the wishlist tab, but the method I'm using for deletion, is looking for that objectID which as I mentioned, doesn't show up until the page is refreshed. Delete movie from wishlist works after a page refresh, but thats not a very pleasant user experience. What would be my best method to come up with a fix that movies can be deleted without needing to reload the page. In newbie terms please. Code below.

```
export const removeMovie = (id) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    await axios.delete(`/wishlist/${id}/delete`)
    dispatch({
      type: REMOVE_MOVIE,
      payload:id
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('unable to delete movie')
    console.error(error)
  }
}
```

```
 case REMOVE_MOVIE:
            return{...state, wishlist:state.wishlist.filter(movie => movie._id !== payload)}
```

```
router.delete('/:id/delete', auth, async  (req, res)=>{
    const movie = await Movie.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id)

    if(!movie){
        res.send('Movie not found')
    } else{
        movie.remove()
        res.send('movie deleted')
    }

})
```

Comment: On your React App when you display the movies in wishlist did you have a **key**?  If possible add code to your React app handling this operations

Comment: i'd try to help if that block of text is tidied up/ what is exactly the issue

Comment: When you add a movie to wishlist you write something to state that doesn't have an id but you need that id when you want to delete it? What are the actions dispatched when you add something, what is the data in those actions? How do they change state? When you add something to wishlist don't you get the id and why don't you save it to state at that point?

Comment: Do you have to delete items by the object ID or are you able to delete objects using an individual movies ID that was set by the API?